# Place pivot under grid in windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am creating a windows phone 8 application. The application has a pivot. The requirement is to have a static block on top of pivot to display data that needs to be present all the time irrespective of which pivot is currently visible. An example of it is AccuWeather application. 
 I have tried place a stackpanel, listview, textbox, etc, but both controls overlays under the same grid, but it does not work.
 Also, I have tried placing another grid on top of the grid that holds the pivot, the page stops showing in this case.
Any pointers/help on how can I resolve the issue?
I have searched the web but unable to find appropriate information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
[<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="SampleStackPivotApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/MainViewModelSampleData.xaml}"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--Static Control Block-->
        <Grid x:Name="StaticContentGrid" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Some Content goes Here" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="Another Content goes Here" ></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>


        <!--Pivot Control-->
        <phone:Pivot Grid.Row="1">
            <phone:Pivot.Title>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Pivot Name Goes here"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
            </phone:Pivot.Title>
            <!--Pivot item one-->
            <phone:PivotItem Header="first">
                <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
                <phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector>
            </phone:PivotItem>

            <!--Pivot item two-->
            <phone:PivotItem Header="second">
                <!--Double line list no text wrapping-->
                <phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineThree}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,-6,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector>
            </phone:PivotItem>
        </phone:Pivot>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>][1]
```